# Edge definitions for a graph database

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, graph

We will be receiving data that conveys the following information:

```
Object1 **is related to** Object2
Object1 **has relationship ID R1** with Object2
```

Both `Object1` and `Object2` are further related to arbitrary number of objects. The 'axis' of `is related to` will be used to answer a query, such as, 'Who is related to Object1', recursively. And, the 'axis' of `has relationship ID R1` will be used to answer a query, such as, 'Who are the parties to the relationship ID R1'.

I have introductory knowledge in Neo4j and the question is not so much about code that does CRUD on such a graph. It seems that, number of edges should be equal to types of queries that (can be foreseen) will run between two vertices.

Can you please guide me a design pattern to define this database?

Comment: Your question is so general. Anyhow, to create the graph, you must mention all nodes and edges (for example:   `a-[:isRelatedTo]-> b`, `b-[:hasRelationshipIDR1]-> a` in cypher language).  I will help you, if write your question in more details.

Comment: Thanks, @OmG. First, I agree, this is a general question. Second, I may not necessarily know in advance all the edges. I may know, the nodes in advance or at least, predict safely. How do I design for that growth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is about the impacts of schema changes due to a growing set of edge types.

In [Graph Engine](https://graphengine.io) you can define edges with values in your schema, so that multiple edge types ('axis') can be represented with a single type, associated with an enum field that indicate the edge type. Then in the query you write:

```
g.V(a).outE(e => e.type == EdgeType.isRelatedTo).outV(b => ...)
g.V(b).outE(e => e.type == EdgeType.hasRelationshipIDR1).outV(a => ...)
```

This pattern is also applicable to backends without explicit support for edges with values, for that you can model an edge as a vertex:

```
g.V(a).outE().outV(e => e.type == EdgeType.isRelatedTo).outE().outV(b => ...)
g.V(b).outE().outV(e => e.type == EdgeType.hasRelationshipIDR1).outE().outV(a => ...)
```

where the cost being an extra step of traversal.

Comment: "If I understand correctly, your concern is about the impacts of schema changes due to a growing set of edge types." That is correct. Thanks for the hint on Graph Engine. (Pleasantly surprised to know that this is from Microsoft!)